# Can we send text data over FM radio?

Tags: radio, frequency-modulation

Can we able to broadcast text data over the FM radio.If yes, how can I implement this.

Comment: Having a clue how FM works would be a good start.

Comment: There are cheap software defined radios out there. But please do some more research before asking your question.

Comment: ever heard of rds? looks like it is possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from RDS-technology there are alternative methods with a much higher bandwidth. One such technology is Acoustic OFDM, used for scientific and experimental applications like underwater data transfer and texting via PA systems.

Acoustic OFDM is basically the same technology as its broadband OFDM cousin used in WiMax, DVB-T, ADSL and some less known communication standards but instead over the much smaller audio bandwidth, generally 20Hz - 20kHz (RDS uses much less and has an extremely low bandwidth). OFDM encodes the sent data and distributes it over multitude of carriers within that audio BW. The resulting spectrum of this signal is noise-like. When mixed with analog sound or speech, the result is simply the same analog audio with a slightly elevated noise level during quieter passages, generally not noticable to the human ear.

Due to the built-in FEC, interleavers, etc, the sent data is virtually immune to interference from the analog sound when decoded in the receiver.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever method you choose, make sure you conform to whatever regulations are relevant to your country/region. Violations can be very expensive.

Restrictions will exist on all combinations of frequency, power, modulation scheme, identification, and licensing.